# Can't adjust screen resolution in VirtualBox guest

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Windows7 on VirtualBox but the even in fullscreen the screen of the virtual machine remains small.

I can't seem to be able to adjust it. Is there any way in the settings to make it 1280x800 resolution?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the Guest Additions are installed inside the Virtual Machine. If you have installed Virtualbox-OSE from the package repo, you can get the iso that holds the additions for Windows machines with the command: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`

Comment: In case you installed from the Oracle repository [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/22745/3940).